# Websphere Portal 8.0 -- display forbidden error instead of redirecting user to first page they have access to see

Tags: websphere-portal

We are using WebSphere Portal 8.0. Currently, when a user tries to access a page they do not have permission to view (via Page Permissions), the Portal redirects them to the first page they do have access to see.

I would prefer that instead of them being redirected to an unrelated page, they instead receive some sort of Forbidden page or 403 error.

Is there a way to configure this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Portal cannot be configured to throw a 403 for these resources, but it can be configured to throw a 404 instead for pages instead of redirecting to the one that is found first for anonymous users. you can use this to instead throw a 404 http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21674823

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thank you!